# Items deleted in Content Hub that were synced to Sitecore XM Cloud via CMP are not deleted in Sitecore XM Cloud

Tags: content-hub, xm-cloud, cmp

We are using CMP to push assets from Content Hub into XM Cloud. The sync from Content Hub to XM Cloud works properly. However, we have observed that when assets are deleted or archived in Content Hub, the corresponding items in XM Cloud are not updated.

I have not found any details or information in the Sitecore documentation or on the greater web about the capability to unpublish or delete Sitecore items synced by CMP from Content Hub. I would need to be able to make the synced Sitecore items no longer appear on the site (whether that means unpublishing them, deleting them, moving them to a different path, or even setting a flag/field I can code against).

Is it possible to handle this sort of data sync from Content Hub to XM Cloud via CMP?